# Factory Boy Circular Import not working as desired

Tags: python, flask, factory-boy

I have 2 models, Account and AccountUser. An Account has many AccountUsers. I'm trying to create this using [Factory Boy's circular imports](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#circular-imports) but have been unsuccessful so far with various changes. There's not much on SO about factory boy, and not enough on Google to help me. Can anyone help me make this work without errors?

I put a pdb at the bottom of stub_account.py and do `acct = AccountFactory()` but I get `*** NameError: name 'AccountFactory' is not defined`. If I do `acct = AccountFactory().build()` or `.create()` I get the same error. If I define those variables inside the script instead of while in pdb I get the same error.

**project_root/app/tests/scripts/stubs/stub_account.py**

```
from app.models import Account
from faker import Faker
import factory

fake = Faker()

class AccountFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Account

    billing_contact = factory.SubFactory(
       "app.tests.scripts.stubs.stub_account_user.AccountUserFactory")
```

**project_root/app/tests/scripts/stubs/stub_account_user.py**

```
from app.models import AccountUser
from faker import Faker
import factory

fake = Faker()

class AccountUserFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountUser

    _parent = factory.SubFactory(AccountFactory)
```

Comment: It's hard to help: what is the issue you're running into? Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: @Xelnor, I updated the post a couple days ago. Sorry to make essentially a useless comment but I'm not sure that editing a post notifies anyone who has commented.

Comment: In Django you need to use `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory` for all factories. I assume for Flask there is a similar abstract class

Answer (score 0):

For reverse foreign key you have to use factory.RelatedFactory